# drf-spectacular with custom permission on endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I've got problem with drf-spectacular library. I prepared decorators for my viewset, but I can't see endpoints in this viewset on my schema. I figured out that my custom permission to these endpoints blocks it (When I set my permissions to AllowAny the schema works fine).

One permission checks if headers include header-x, the second one asks db about something (simple Queryset).

Is there an option to allow swagger to disable these permissions? Or I must to refactor my code to delete them?

I tried to modify DRF-spectacular settings, but I couldn't find the proper way to solve it. But when I change SERVE PUBLIC to True I see everything, even though I'm not authorized. I want to show mentioned endpoint only when I'm authorized.

```
"TITLE": "My API",
"DESCRIPTION": "My description",
"SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA": False,
'SERVE_PUBLIC': False,
```